Ubuntu Studio 23.10 bluetooth Sony WH-CH520 headphone does not connect anymore
Sony WH-CH520 connected on desktop with TP-Link bluetooth 5.0 UB500 dongle was working fine.
Suddenly,the connection is lost and the adapter does not detect the headphones anymore.
Headphones work still fine with smartphone on other devices.
I am on Ubuntu Studio 23.10.
Thank you in advance for any advice.

https://askubuntu.com/a/1534431/380330

Ok. I found the solution. After checking the bluetooth adapter, it was clear the problem could only come from the headphones. After resetting to the factory state, it worked again.
If this can help...
